# MonoDroid - Beginner

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and the Mono Droid v1.0.1 to begin programming in C # for the Android platform.

I have a problem. From the main Activity want to call another activty ('prueba'), it does well, but I do not show anything on the screen. That is, show me a new screen with the title 'prueba' but did not show anything in it (it's all in black).

This is the code I'm using:

- ## AndroidManifest.xml

  ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   android:installLocation="internalOnly" package="MonoAndroidApplication1.MonoAndroidApplication1.apk" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="Primera">

  <application android:label="MonoAndroidApplication1">
  </application>
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <activity android:name=".Prueba" />
  </manifest>
  ```
- ## Activity1.cs

  ```
  using System;
  using Android.App;
  using Android.Content;
  using Android.Runtime;
  using Android.Views;
  using Android.Widget;
  using Android.OS;
  using System.IO;

  namespace MonoAndroidApplication1
  {

   [Activity(Label = "MonoAndroidApplication1", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]

  public class Activity1 : Activity
  {
      EditText et01;
      EditText et02;
      EditText et03;

      Button bt01;
      Button bt02;
      Button bt03;

      protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
      {
          base.OnCreate(bundle);

          SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

          et01 = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.edittext01);
          et02 = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.edittext02);
          et03 = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.edittext03);
          bt01 = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.button01);
          bt02 = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.button02);
          bt03 = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.button03);

          bt01.Click += (sender, e) =>
          {
              et01.Text = string.Format("Click en 1");
          };
          bt02.Click += (sender, e) =>
          {
              et02.Text = string.Format("Click en 2");
          };
          bt03.Click += (sender, e) =>
          {
              et03.Text = string.Format("Click en 3");
              Intent i = new Intent(this, typeof(Prueba));
              StartActivity(i);
          };

          Toast.MakeText(this, "Esto es un ejemplo", ToastLength.Short).Show();
       }
     }
   }
  ```
- ## Prueba.cs

  ```
  using System;
  using Android.App;
  using Android.Content;
  using Android.Runtime;
  using Android.Views;
  using Android.Widget;
  using Android.OS;
  using System.IO;

  namespace MonoAndroidApplication1
  {
      [Activity(Label = "Prueba", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
      public class Prueba : Activity
      {
          public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
          {
               SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Prueba);
          }
      }
   }
  ```
- ## Prueba.axml

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <AbsoluteLayout
   android:id="@+id/widget0"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  >
    <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textoif"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="IF-Software"
   >
  </TextView>
  ```
- ## Main.axml

  ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/widget27"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
   >
     <TableRow
      android:id="@+id/widget28"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
     >
       <TextView
        android:id="@+id/widget32"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Prueba IF"
       >
       </TextView>
     </TableRow>
     <TableRow
      android:id="@+id/widget29"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
     >
       <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
       >
      </EditText>
      <Button
       android:id="@+id/button01"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="1"
      >
      </Button>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
     android:id="@+id/widget30"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
      <EditText
       android:id="@+id/edittext02"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:textSize="18sp"
      >
      </EditText>
      <Button
       android:id="@+id/button02"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="2"
      >
      </Button>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
     android:id="@+id/widget31"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
      <EditText
       android:id="@+id/edittext03"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:textSize="18sp"
     >
     </EditText>
     <Button
      android:id="@+id/button03"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="3"
     >
     </Button>
   </TableRow>
  </TableLayout>
  ```

Comment: Too much code, you should isolate what is causing the problem, for instance have you tried replacing your activity with a different one? If that other activity works, then your base activity is not likely to be the problem.

Comment: You aren't calling `base.OnCreate` in `Prueba`, is that intentional?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not a MonoDroid developer, but I do notice that your missing the "override" keyword on the second activity onCreate and also not calling the parent.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll want to remove MainLauncher = true from Prueba.cs. That is used to indicate what activity should be started when the app launches.

http://docs.mono-android.net/index.aspx?link=P%3aAndroid.App.ActivityAttribute.MainLauncher

Answer (score 0):

The Mono-esque way to add most (if not all, not sure) "manifest options" is through the attributes of the class implementing the activity (or service).

The Visual Studio Mono plugin automatically generates the manifest, so its best not to
manually tamper with it (I'm sure there are cases where there is no other option).

For example:

```
[Activity(Label="MonoDroid App", MainLauncher=true, Permission="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE")]
public class MonoActivity : Activity
{
  protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bindle)
  {
    base.OnCreate(bindle);
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually, I see now that this WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE setting is a user-permission, and if set the way it is above, will appear as a activity setting (android:permission) and not a user-permission in the manifest file. Oh, I just remembered, you set the user-permissions user the project properties in VS (its a checkbox list of all the permissions).

Comment: They are actually "uses-permission" tags, not "user-permission", but aside from that everything else holds true.